# Best index strategies for read-only table?

Tags: sql-server, database-design, index

I have a table in SQL Server which has following characteristics:

- will contain about 1.2M records.
- first is empty, will be inserted in batch many times (precisely, 64 times), 20-100k records/each
- the data will not be updated or deleted, just be queried
- the number of concurrent query is high, each query return only one record
- there's nothing to do with the ID (because of the records are not updated or deleted)
- the key of queries is two field, PROVINCE_ID and CANDIDATE_NUMBER (unique across the table)

I'm thinking about creating clustered index on the ID column, and non-clustered index in (PROVINCE_ID,CANDIDATE_NUMBER). will it the best choice? Can you give me another suggestion? please explain why should I do that?

Thank you so much!

Comment: How many other fields are there in the table? Will the queries most likely only read some of them, or all of them equally?

Comment: @Tommi: it's about 10 other fields, such as first name, family name, point1,2...6, total point, all of them are read equally @Mitch Wheat: I don't think 54% is a bad rate. Whenever an answer solves my problem, I accept it right away. If it does not, why should I do? Please look at my list of questions for that

Comment: Often the quality of the questions or unrealistic expectations are factors. I consider 54% with 99 questions to be *very low*. For instance, you left out what should have been some obviously required info in this question initially.

Comment: @Andrew Barber is right.  IF you have asked 100 questions and barely half have satisfactory answers, the problem isn't everyone else :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the ID column is not used for data retrieval, I suggest you place the clustered index on the PROVINCE_ID, CANDIDATE_NUMBER columns instead.

If some columns are read very often compared to others, consider adding an index with PROVINCE_ID, CANDIDATE_NUMBER plus that column. That way the queries can get everything they need from the index itself and don't need to look at the table at all.

Comment: If he clusters on `Province_ID, Candidate_Number`, all the data will be in the index regardless (that's the nature of a clustered index).

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't going to ever have any other fields in your `WHERE` clause than those two, by all means cluster on `PROVINCE_ID, CANDIDATE_NUMBER`.  If you have additional criteria you will be selecting on, consider a covering index.

The above also assumes both those fields are `INT` data types.  If they are string types (`varchar`, `char`, `nvarchar`) then create an `INT IDENTITY` field and cluster on that.  If you cluster on wide data types like strings, it uses a **lot** more space per row, and that is multiplied by the number of indexes you have (since the cluster key is in each row of every non-clustered index).

Also bear in mind that if you cluster on `PROVINCE_ID, CANDIDATE_NUMBER` and use a `WHERE` clause that only filters on `CANDIDATE_NUMBER`, then the index won't be used at all.  In a data warehousing situation like this, you generally want to have an index that covers all your queries.